# how to remove a word from a string

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

hello i am a beginner in objective-c
i have a nsstring like this

```
Select *  from Store_Master where AND  VDivison = 'Casual Dining' AND VBrand_Name = 'Pinkberry' AND VCountry_Name = 'Egypt' AND VCity = 'Cairo' AND VBuilding_mall_name = 'Dandy Mega Mall' GROUP BY VStore_Name
```

i want to just remove first occurance of AND,how can i remove.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange` to replace only the first 'AND':

```
NSString* s = @"Select *  from Store_Master where AND  VDivison = 'Casual Dining' AND VBrand_Name = 'Pinkberry' AND VCountry_Name = 'Egypt' AND VCity = 'Cairo' AND VBuilding_mall_name = 'Dandy Mega Mall' GROUP BY VStore_Name";
NSRange replaceRange = [s rangeOfString:@"AND"];
if (replaceRange.location != NSNotFound){
    NSString* result = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:replaceRange withString:@""];
}
```

That would result in:

```
Select *  from Store_Master where   VDivison = 'Casual Dining' AND VBrand_Name = 'Pinkberry' AND VCountry_Name = 'Egypt' AND VCity = 'Cairo' AND VBuilding_mall_name = 'Dandy Mega Mall' GROUP BY VStore_Name
```

EDITED:

If you want to remove the occurrences of `AND` in a case insensitive way (no matter uppercase of lowercase), use the `NSStringCompareOptions` when you create the NSRange, like this:

```
NSRange replaceRange = [s rangeOfString:@"and" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

The rest of the code is the same.

Comment: I've edited my answer to avoid NSRangeException, I had assumed that the string and the token to replace were both well known, thank you @Nit

Comment: thank u its working with above string but if string will change like this---"Select v1.VEmployee_Number, v1.VEmployee_Name,v1.VJob_Title,v1.VCountry_Name,v1.VLocation_Type,v4.VCity,(case when  (v1.VLocation_Type = 'HO') then v1.VBr_Name ELSE v1.VDivision end) as Data_Br_Divison from Store_User  as v1,Store_Master as v4 where  and v1.VBrand_Name = 'Bhs' and v1.VCountry_Name = 'Kuwait' GROUP BY v1.VEmployee_Name" then its not removing..

Comment: You should use the `NSStringCompareOptions` when you create the `NSRange`, to set it case insensitive. You should do `NSRange replaceRange = [s rangeOfString:@"and" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];`

Comment: @kamlesh please tell me if this works, and mark the answer as correct if it solves the problem, so that others can find it easier

Comment: its still not working with above string.

which i gave u later

Comment: Use this: NSString* s = @"Select v1.VEmployee_Number, v1.VEmployee_Name,v1.VJob_Title,v1.VCountry_Name,v1.VLocation_Type,v4.VCity,(cas‌​e when (v1.VLocation_Type = 'HO') then v1.VBr_Name ELSE v1.VDivision end) as Data_Br_Divison from Store_User as v1,Store_Master as v4 where and v1.VBrand_Name = 'Bhs' and v1.VCountry_Name = 'Kuwait' GROUP BY v1.VEmployee_Name";
    NSRange replaceRange = [s rangeOfString:@"AND" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (replaceRange.location != NSNotFound){
        NSLog(@"--- %@", [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:replaceRange withString:@""]);
    }

Comment: I just tried what i posted in previous comment and it works, removing the first occurrence of 'and' ("...v4 where **and** v1.VBrand_Nam...")

Comment: So please mark the answer as correct so that others can take advantage of it

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *String1 = @"Select *  from Store_Master where AND  VDivison = 'Casual Dining' AND VBrand_Name = 'Pinkberry' AND VCountry_Name = 'Egypt' AND VCity = 'Cairo' AND VBuilding_mall_name = 'Dandy Mega Mall' GROUP BY VStore_Name";
NSString *String2 = [String1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AND" withString:@""];



NSString * aString  = @"Select *  from Store_Master where AND  VDivison = 'Casual Dining' AND VBrand_Name = 'Pinkberry' AND VCountry_Name = 'Egypt' AND VCity = 'Cairo' AND VBuilding_mall_name = 'Dandy Mega Mall' GROUP BY VStore_Name";
NSRange replaceRange = [aString rangeOfString:@"AND"];
if (replaceRange.location !=NSNotFound){
    NSString * newString = [aString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:replaceRange withString:@""];
    NSLog(newString);
}
```

Comment: That will replace all occurrences of 'AND', not only the first one as he wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *s = @"your string";
NSInteger loc = [s rangeOfString: @"AND"].location;
if (loc != NSNotFound) s = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", [s substringToIndex: loc], [s substringFromIndex: loc + 3]];
```

This will remove the first occurrence of AND.  The second line finds the location of the first occurrence.  The third line gets the substring before and after and puts them together using stringWithFormat.

After getting the location, there are other ways to do remove it, such as find-replace given a range using `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange`, or doing it like my example but using `stringByAppendingString` to concatenate the parts.

Comment: thanks for answering but with following string its not working i dont know why

"Select v1.VEmployee_Number, v1.VEmployee_Name,v1.VJob_Title,v1.VCountry_Name,v1.VLocation_Type,v4.VCity,(cas‌​e when (v1.VLocation_Type = 'HO') then v1.VBr_Name ELSE v1.VDivision end) as Data_Br_Divison from Store_User as v1,Store_Master as v4 where and v1.VBrand_Name = 'Bhs' and v1.VCountry_Name = 'Kuwait' GROUP BY v1.VEmployee_Name"